# The proper way to interrupt a python program with sub-process and threads

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

right now, I'm developing a program that includes some thread processes and subprocesses the thing, is that they are classes with threads and others with sub-processes. 
And I want to be able to kill the program with Ctrl-C or Delete as you would with the Keyboard Interrupt,

In the exception block to run some ending script to close all open files and end all properly... But I'm keeping track of all the threads in a list of unfinished threads, but I still have an issue on how to track the subprocesses so I can kill them properly...

The thing that I'm wondering if that if, there is a global way to kill all routines process? , including the process not just daemon threads.

Comment: ***In the exception block to run some ending script to close all open files and end all properly*** : All sub-processes will most certainly be closed when the "master" process exits. Give it a try.

Comment: I am doing it like that but sometimes, It gets stuck in a process, I can see the process in the task manager, but the python script is already dead. Not sure if it's windows, or the way the subprocess work. I haven't tried it in linux, the idea of this, is to be able to run it in both windows, and linux, so... may be in linux works, but in windows it does weird stuff.